# Business people who became governors or mayors in a major city?

Tags: united-states, history

Apart from Bloomberg, what other business people became governors or mayors of major cities in the USA?

Businesses worth at least 100 million and first 10 cities by population.

Business owners or top executives

Comment: To get the ball rolling: Mitt Romney (Bain Capital, Governor of Massachusetts). Few potentials here if anyone wants to follow up http://www.nbcnews.com/id/39800329/ns/business-us_business/t/business-leaders-politics-their-blood/

Comment: I feel like this list would be too numerous to count. Surely this has happened more times than we think.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a fair few recent state governors who are also businesspeople in companies worth over $100 million.

- Nelson Rockefeller, Governor of New York 1959-73, Various; Chase Bank, Rockefeller Center...
- Mitt Romney, Governor of Massachusetts 1985-2013, Bain Capital
- Mark Warner, Governor of Virginia 2002-06, Nextel Communications
- Jon Corzine, Governor of New Jersey 2006-2010, Goldman Sachs
- Bill Haslam, Governor of Tennessee 2011-19, Pilot Corp., Saks Fifth Avenue
- Bruce Rauner, Governor of Illinois 2015-19, GTCR LLC
- Jim Justice, Governor of West Virginia 2017- , Bluestone Industries, Bluestone Coal Corporation
- J.B. Pritzker, Governor of Illinois 2019- , Pritzker Group
- Jared Polis, Governor of Colorado 2019- , ProFlowers

As far as city mayors go, the best example I can think of off the top of my head aside from Bloomberg is Tom Leppert, 59th Mayor of Dallas, and former CEO of Kaplan Inc.

In addition, although not in the top 10 most populous cities, Bill Haslam also served as mayor of Knoxville, TN.

Comment: Some of those are arguable.  For instance, Rockefeller was an heir, only incidentially (if that)  in business.  Schwarzenegger was an actor, not primarily a business person.

Comment: Are you sure that Bluestone Farms ever was a $100 000 000 corporation? "Current estimates show this company has an annual revenue of 1887272 and employs a staff of approximately 30." Schwarzenegger never owned a big corporation unless you count himself as a corporation, There is no doubt that he has $100 000 000

Comment: @JCAA Thanks, I really meant to complete that list with the other Bluestone companies, some of which are definitely worth over $100m. I'm happy to remove Schwarzenegger as I see he could be arguable.

Comment: You may also check Pritzker and his ownership of Hayatt. 
He does belong to a  family who owned Hayatt. But "Pritzker founded 1871, the non-profit small business incubator that has helped entrepreneurs create more than 11,000 jobs and more than 1,000 new companies. Since the creation of 1871, Chicago has been named one of the top ten technology startup hubs in the world, and 1871 was named the best incubator in the world. "

Comment: Can anyone help me to rewrite the qursestion so it has a cahnce to be opened again? Thanks

Comment: You may make the question better by including some examples from this list and saying why these examples satisfy (not satisfy) your conditions. I actually think there are very few people who satisfy your conditions (at most one). Going from business to politics is common but leaving a 100 mil corporation to become a mayor is very rare.